# Ubuntu 11.10 Mobile broadband connected but no internet access

Tags: networking, connection, broadband

I am able to establish a mobile broadband connection but I still don't have access to internet. The mobile broadband works without any issues from Windows 7 on the same machine.

I configured the mobile broadband connection in the unity network manager. I chose the only available device, "Dell DW5550", provided my country and ISP and specified "MMS" as the plan.

When I choose the mobile broadband connection it says "connection established" and appears to have an IP address:

```
$ ifconfig
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:80:37:ec:02:00  
          inet addr:172.29.128.133  Bcast:172.29.128.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
```

but I cannot resolve any internet host names:

```
$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

How can I diagnose and/or solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by configuring the connection to use "Broadband" as the plan instead of "MMS".